# Cannot print ASCII table from ! to ~ 10 i.e., characters per line and characters are separated by one space by while loop

Tags: python

When I use this code my terminal shows full ASCII characters but it does not fullfil the requirement of my question which is to display 10 ASCII characters per line where characters are separated by one space using a `while` loop:

```
i = 1
while i < 127:    
    result = chr(i)
    print(result)          
 
    i = i + 1
```

every character is on it's own line.

When I use this code

```
i = 1
while i < 127:    
    result = chr(i)
    print(result,sep=' ', end=" ")          
 
    i = i + 1
```

ASCII character are displayed like this after 17 spaces

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by '17 decimal point'?

Comment: It means the output starts from 17 decimal number which is converted to char instead of 1(!)...                                                                                                                                 The Question is: (Display the ASCII character table) Write a program that displays the characters
in the ASCII character table from ! to ~. Display ten characters per line. The characters are separated by exactly one space                                                      The answer of this Question is available by for loop but I want to do it by while loop...

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please explain what you've tried to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure what you mean with 17 decimal number but I think I know what you want to do.
The problem is that you don't know how to switch between spaces and a newline if I understand correctly.
We want to print a newline every 10 characters, and otherwise print a space. An easy way to do this in python is to use the [modulo function](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html). With it you can get the remainder of a division. If we divide our iterator `i` by 10, we get 0 as a remainder every 10 iterations. We can use this to print a newline every 10 iterations like this:

```py
i = 1
while i < 127-32:
    result = chr(i+32)
    
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(result)
    else:
        print(result, end=' ')
 
    i = i + 1
```

You also said it had to be from `!` to `~`. In asciim printable characters start at 32, so we need to start add 32 to the number in `chr()` to make sure we are not printing the non-printable characters.
This will print the ascii table with all printable characters like this:

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) *
+ , - . / 0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = >
? @ A B C D E F G H
I J K L M N O P Q R
S T U V W X Y Z [ \
] ^ _ ` a b c d e f
g h i j k l m n o p
q r s t u v w x y z
{ | } ~
```

Answer (score 1):

You can gather the start and endvalues of `'!'` and `'~'` via the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) to remove magic numbers from your code:

> **ord(c)**
> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing
> the Unicode code point of that character. For example, `ord('a')` returns the integer
> 97 and `ord('€')` (Euro sign) returns 8364. This is the inverse of `chr()`.

Then print them, add a space if the line is not yet done or a newline if you are done for this line.

```
start = ord("!")
end = ord("~")

i = start
while i <= end:
    print(chr(i), end="")   # print the character
    i += 1
    if (i - start) % 10 == 0: # check if we printed 10 characters in this line
        print()
    else:
        print(" ", end="")
```

Output:

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) *
+ , - . / 0 1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = >
? @ A B C D E F G H
I J K L M N O P Q R
S T U V W X Y Z [ \
] ^ _ ` a b c d e f
g h i j k l m n o p
q r s t u v w x y z
{ | } ~
```